# Accented characters (à, é, ù) declared outside res/values/strings not supported with "ant debug"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, utf-8

Most of the strings we used come from the strings.xml file and there is no issue.

But some strings are written with a StringBuilder or come from Params.java file that hold static values. The accented characters are not displayed (usual question mark) if the .apk is built with command lines `ant clean` and `ant debug`. No problem if Eclipse build it.

I understand that the .java files are encoded in Cp1252. But it causes an error only for ANT.

Anyone knows why or how to solve the issue ?

Comment: First, you should never use Cp1252 for your projects or this is what happens. Try changing the encoding of the entire project (eclipse -> project properties), then you should open your java files (for example with winedt) and replace the wrong encoded chars.

Comment: Thanks ! indeed it works. I wish you could explain me why the eclipse build work flawlessly but not the ANT command one ?  What are the downside of not using the Cp1252 from Java ? Why not use utf-16 ?

Comment: Forget it, That results in 395 characters across the project to replace 00

Comment: Well I replace that 395 characters one by one -_- Problem solved I guess but not explained. Thanks for the pointer !

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how javac compile your .java file. Probably eclipse use `javac -encoding Cp1252` while ant use the system default encoding.